# How to Enable Dart Sealed Classes in Dart 3 Alpha (master branch)

Tags: dart

I'm trying to test out sealed classes in the Dart Master branch, but I keep running into this error (it is showing up as a lint error over the `sealed` keyword in VSCode):

```
This requires the 'sealed-class' language feature to be enabled.
Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 3.0.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.
```

Steps I have taken so far:

1. Setting my `pubspec.yaml` file environment parameter to be inclusive of version 3.0.0
2. Including the `sealed-class` language feature in my `analysis_options.yaml` file.
3. Changing channel to master with by setting `flutter channel master` in terminal.
4. Repeatedly running `flutter clean`, `flutter pub cache repair`, `flutter upgrade`.

Has anyone else been able to get this to work? Below are some snippets from the relevant files.

pubspec.yaml:

```
...
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.2 <=3.0.0'
...
```

(NOTE: On this one, I've tried various configurations in this parameter: '3.0.0', '3.0.0-290.0.dev', '>=2.18.2'. The first was not allowed, the others led to the same issue.)

My analysis_options.yaml file has the following:

```
...
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - records
    - patterns
    - sealed-class

linter:
...
```

And here's what I get with `flutter --version`:

```
Flutter 3.9.0-1.0.pre.55 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d696b05165 (26 hours ago) • 2023-03-06 11:41:59 +0000
Engine • revision 197b6dae1c
Tools • Dart 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-290.0.dev) • DevTools 2.22.2
```

Comment: have you tried experimental flag? https://dart.dev/tools/experiment-flags  
   https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/tools/experimental_features.yaml

Comment: You have to pass in the flags at the command line as well, when you run the program, not just in the `analysis_options.yaml` file. I would try `3.0.0-290.0.dev` as the minimum sdk in the `pubspec.yaml` as well.

Comment: I am getting the error as a lint error in VS Code, shouldn't analysis options be the right place to prevent that from happening? If I do it this way, will I just get the error until I try to run the program?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming the experiment flag works the same in command line for `flutter run` as it does for `dart run`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, changing

```
environment:
  sdk: '3.0.6'
```

in my pubspec.yaml file works!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what it was but I did get an update to VSCode at some point and then it seemed to be working in the linter. But then had to use the experimental flag in command line as mentioned by @Olga P and @mmcdon20 when I wanted to use it in running the app.

Answer (score 1):

i am using the latest version of flutter i had this **environment:
sdk: '>=2.19.6 <3.0.0'** before
but now i changed to this
**environment:
sdk: '3.1.5'
**

it works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).